# API post button with ajax html response for my code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, api

Please, I want my users to click on a button for them to send this request. Then a response will be displayed to shown to them. The response is final, and the button cannot be clicked again.

```
> <?php // Your code here! $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch,
> CURLOPT_URL,
> "https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v1/bank-transfer/reserved-accounts");
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_setopt($ch,
> CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{  ."accountName": "John Snow
> Limited",   "accountReference": "jsnow1234",   "currencyCode": "NGN", 
>  "contractCode": "4934121686",   "customerName": "John Snow Limited", 
>  "customerEmail": "john@snow.com",   "incomeSplitConfig": [
>     {
>       "": "MFY_SUB_319452883228",
>       "splitPercentage": 20,
>       "feePercentage": 10,
>       "feeBearer": true
>     }   ] }'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(   "Content-Type: application/json",   "Authorization: Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsibW9ubmlmeS1wYXltZW50LWVuZ2luZSJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJwcm9maWxlIl0sImV4cCI6MTU3NjA3MTY2NywiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiTVBFX1JFVFJJRVZFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfREVMRVRFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfUkVUUklFVkVfUkVTRVJWRURfQUNDT1VOVF9UUkFOU0FDVElPTlMiLCJNUEVfSU5JVElBTElaRV9QQVlNRU5UIiwiTVBFX1JFU0VSVkVfQUNDT1VOVCIsIk1QRV9DQU5fUkVUUklFVkVfVFJBTlNBQ1RJT04iXSwianRpIjoiODNjMjNiNjgtMGZlNS00OTEzLTg2ZTEtNmE2NjhjYzU4YjZkIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiTUtfVEVTVF9WUjdKM1VBQUNIIn0.p89bvBs9OP71U6wS10M6z4fh4lo7S9Yb185AOQvua8LaPyiGbFob5T-ASaeEH2-csZ2BDWNgw0QHB1P3UUIDkgk6ffuc58Mjuz2o9hGRr6ch6U7OpU_vaYzwZprBuw4ywKDx1RH7LkjaOcMZsa0eNVxec5hvuql9lZH99FT-72GC54RFijF7W9NKPccqlELWPXPmRV98WrkTRPcKbgI4zvd63HMQky7zYQHrBpniHbOS-2SiTROAI1zxJxs2Pv9h-9_i0JhnCz4NNOhdhNPLtbt6ZLqNBYkK10rJ3te8BJOpOIXwxxLd7q42oQ6MUVXP1UtqMRNVnC_kYZqbCmCbkA"
> )); $response = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); var_dump($response);
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service; you need to make an attempt yourself, and then give us an actual problem description, if you can’t manage to achieve it on your own. A mere “I want” is not a proper question to be asked here on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> button click fire one action you using issets() with post method and control action like this example
> ```

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

    <?PHP
        if(iseet($_POST['submit'])){
        
         // Your code here! $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch,
         CURLOPT_URL,
         "https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v1/bank-transfer/reserved-accounts");
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_setopt($ch,
         CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{  ."accountName": "John Snow
         Limited",   "accountReference": "jsnow1234",   "currencyCode": "NGN", 
          "contractCode": "4934121686",   "customerName": "John Snow Limited", 
          "customerEmail": "john@snow.com",   "incomeSplitConfig": [
             {
               "": "MFY_SUB_319452883228",
               "splitPercentage": 20,
               "feePercentage": 10,
               "feeBearer": true
             }   ] }'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(   "Content-Type: application/json",   "Authorization: Bearer
         eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsibW9ubmlmeS1wYXltZW50LWVuZ2luZSJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJwcm9maWxlIl0sImV4cCI6MTU3NjA3MTY2NywiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiTVBFX1JFVFJJRVZFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfREVMRVRFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfUkVUUklFVkVfUkVTRVJWRURfQUNDT1VOVF9UUkFOU0FDVElPTlMiLCJNUEVfSU5JVElBTElaRV9QQVlNRU5UIiwiTVBFX1JFU0VSVkVfQUNDT1VOVCIsIk1QRV9DQU5fUkVUUklFVkVfVFJBTlNBQ1RJT04iXSwianRpIjoiODNjMjNiNjgtMGZlNS00OTEzLTg2ZTEtNmE2NjhjYzU4YjZkIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiTUtfVEVTVF9WUjdKM1VBQUNIIn0.p89bvBs9OP71U6wS10M6z4fh4lo7S9Yb185AOQvua8LaPyiGbFob5T-ASaeEH2-csZ2BDWNgw0QHB1P3UUIDkgk6ffuc58Mjuz2o9hGRr6ch6U7OpU_vaYzwZprBuw4ywKDx1RH7LkjaOcMZsa0eNVxec5hvuql9lZH99FT-72GC54RFijF7W9NKPccqlELWPXPmRV98WrkTRPcKbgI4zvd63HMQky7zYQHrBpniHbOS-2SiTROAI1zxJxs2Pv9h-9_i0JhnCz4NNOhdhNPLtbt6ZLqNBYkK10rJ3te8BJOpOIXwxxLd7q42oQ6MUVXP1UtqMRNVnC_kYZqbCmCbkA"
         )); $response = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); var_dump($response);
        
        } 
         ?>
```